# Is there a way to do Scriban partial templates?

Tags: sxa, scriban

In MVC there's the concept of Partial Views which helps refactor common code that can be reused by other Views.

Is there a similar concept in SXA Scriban?

Ideal example:

List of Links Template:

```
{{ for i_links in i_datasource.FooterLinks.children }}
    {{ render "Custom Partial" i_datasource }}
{{ end }}
```

Custom Partial:

```
<h6>{{ i_datasource.Title }}</h6>
{{ i_datasource.text }}
{{ i_datasource.link }}
```

It would be good to declare this `Custom Partial` in a global scope for the current site so it's not tied to any rendering variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maarten Willebrands has just released a module that can do this: https://www.maartenwillebrands.nl/2021/02/23/sitecore-sxa-scriban-includes/

> Within plain Scriban it is possible to use includes, which allows you
> to render another Scriban template where you call the include. This
> makes sure you can re-use parts of your templates, and makes sure you
> can define your templates in a modular way.

> SXA does not offer the include function out of the box, but luckily
> for us, there are enough extensions points. I’ve developed a SXA
> module called Sitecore Scriban Extensions, which makes it possible to
> use includes within SXA. All the code and Sitecore items that are
> needed are located on this [GitHub](https://github.com/mwillebrands/sitecore-scriban-extensions) page, and you can download a
> [Sitecore Installation Package](https://github.com/mwillebrands/sitecore-scriban-extensions/releases/) as well.

I didn't test it yet (on my to-do list), but it looks very interesting.